# How to do basic validation on React Boostrap 5 input

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-bootstrap

I have the following code and `e.target.value` prints nothing.

Just want to do some basic input validation for an email field.

```
  const handleRegister = (e) => {
    setComingSoonModalState(true);
    alert(e.target.value);
  }
  
  return (
  <div id="app" className="d-flex h-100 flex-column loading-background">
    <div id="loading">
        <div className="faded-text-container">
          <Fader text="autackathon2021"/>
          <InputGroup size="sm" className="input-register">
            <FormControl placeholder="email" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" required/>
            <Button id="register-button" variant="danger" onClick={handleRegister}>register</Button>
          </InputGroup>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  )
```

This can't be that hard and really needs to be in the docs.

---

EDIT: All this cum-guzzling over libraries and they still make us write raw javascript. Yeh yeh yeh it should be a regex but honestly cbf...

```
  var address = ""
  function isValidEmailAddress(address) {
    return !! address.match(/.+@.+/);
  }
  function addToString(e){
    address = e.target.value;
  }

  const handleRegister = () => {
    var symbol_at = address.includes("@")
    var symbol_period = address.includes(".")
    var symbol_tld = address.includes("com");
    if(symbol_at && symbol_period && symbol_tld){
      alert("sometimes you just gotta roll your own basic features");
    }
  }
  
  return (
  <div id="app" className="d-flex h-100 flex-column loading-background">
    <div id="loading">
        <div className="faded-text-container">
          <Fader text="autackathon2021"/>
          <InputGroup size="sm" className="input-register">
            <FormControl name="email" placeholder="email" onChange={addToString}aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"/>
            <Button id="register-button" variant="danger" onClick={handleRegister}>register</Button>
          </InputGroup>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
import SimpleReactValidator from "simple-react-validator";

// inside the component or if you're using class then define it createref inside the constructor
const simpleValidator = useRef(
    new SimpleReactValidator({
        autoForceUpdate: { forceUpdate: forceUpdate },
    }),
);

// inside the submit methods
const formValid = simpleValidator.current.allValid();
if (!formValid) {
    simpleValidator.current.showMessages();
    forceUpdate(1);
    return;
}

// below input tag
{simpleValidator.current.message(
        "full name", // this is name of your field
        full_name, // state variable
        "required",
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Try Using simple-react-validator!`

```
import SimpleReactValidator from "simple-react-validator";

// inside the component or if you're using class then define it createref inside the constructor
const simpleValidator = useRef(
    new SimpleReactValidator({
        autoForceUpdate: { forceUpdate: forceUpdate },
    }),
);

// inside the submit methods
const formValid = simpleValidator.current.allValid();
if (!formValid) {
    simpleValidator.current.showMessages();
    forceUpdate(1);
    return;
}

// below input tag
{simpleValidator.current.message(
        "full name", // this is name of your field
        full_name, // state variable
        "required",
)}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that doesn't work properly with either Hooks or bootstrap not sure which.

Comment: Dude, check the library, there is everything written over there. That's a different case if you wanna go throw by your own!

Comment: Fair. If it works for ppl then that's awesome... tbh tho I'm kind of at the stage now where if I can't find it then it doesn't exist. Docs are just so shocking nowadays and what I end up finding is just overkill in terms of code. It's probably me haha but yeh... Anyway thanks again for the suggestion man.